# trouble with the index PHP

Tags: php, post, syntax, indexing

```
for($c=1;$c<=$num;$c++)
{

$row=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$quiztitle` WHERE id=$c"));

        if($row['answer']==$_POST['answer'][$c]) // NOT WORKING
            {
                echo "correct";
                echo "<br>";
            }

        else
            {
                echo "incorrect";
                echo "<br>";
            }
    }
```

on the line where it says "NOT WORKING",
the index [$c] does not get the value from the loop.
but when i specify it and change it to $_POST['answer1'], it is working.
what is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: FYI, Executing query in a loop is not the best solution.

Comment: do you have any suggestions then?

Comment: Not too sure how you are processing the whole procedure. But you can optimize a bit by executing query once by using (WHERE id IN (1,2,3,,n) or WHERE id >0 AND id < $num ) and save the result in an array before the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

for($c=1;$c<=$num;$c++)
    {

```
 $row=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$quiztitle` WHERE id=$c"));

    if($row['answer']==$_POST['answer'.$c]) // NOT WORKING
        {
            echo "correct";
            echo "<br>";
        }

    else
        {
            echo "incorrect";
            echo "<br>";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're treating 'answer' as an array here, looking for an index within.

You want to concatenate the value.

```
if($row['answer']==$_POST["answer{$c}'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your note, it looks like you want:

```
$_POST["answer$c"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct is:

```
if ($row['answer'] == $_POST['answer' . $c]) {
  ....
}
```